# I have created Site Web through Flutter Web & AWS available from https. But no answer from php reading Mysql

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, flutter, apache, https

I have created Site Web through Flutter Web   & AWS available from https. But no answer when I run  php reading Mysql database
flutter code :
In http Uri url = Uri.parse("http://www.paulcode.com/db.php");
http.Response response = await http.get(url);

---

in https it  doesnt  work while others content is available
in http it works

---

I use apache2 on ubuntu
I have no idea where to investigate. Thanks by advance

Comment: http://www.paulcode.com/db.php 
This URL gives 404 Error

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information:

You can look into the apache2 logs into the Ec2 Instance and add them to the questions

If you are tying to enable SSL for your website, Please look into https://letsencrypt.org/ and try to generate SSL certs using certbot

Answer (score 0):

Your SSL certificate expired ‎Friday ‎30 ‎July ‎2021. You need to renew your SSL certificate.